# C# Create Json file from two clases in one file in the same string

Tags: c#, json, class, configuration, save

can you please help me. I need to create json from two different clases
Here what I have:

```
public class SmtpData
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string settingName { get; set; }
    public string host { get; set; }
    public int port { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string senderName { get; set; }
    public string senderEmail { get; set; }
    public string senderMessageIdDomain { get; set; }
    public string senderReplyTo { get; set; }
    public string senderListUnsubscribe { get; set; }
    public bool isSecure { get; set; }
    public bool isUseProxy { get; set; }
    public class Proxy
    {
        public string proxyhost { get; set; }
        public int proxyport { get; set; }
        public string proxyusername { get; set; }
        public string proxypassword { get; set; }

    }
```

And from this, I create a json file with my configs

```
        public void SaveSmtp(SmtpData data)
        {
            var dataJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            string resultPath = Path.Combine(Helpers.SmtpPath, $"{data.id}.conf");
            File.WriteAllText(resultPath, dataJson);
        }
```

I need to have configs in this file, not only from SmtpData, but with SmtpData.Proxy in the same string

Here is what I have:
{"id":"YXe1yCcNlc","settingName":"AAAA","host":"AAAA","port":0,"username":"AAAA","password":"AAAA","senderName":"AAAA","senderEmail":"AAAA","senderMessageIdDomain":"AAAA","senderReplyTo":"AAAA","senderListUnsubscribe":"AAAA","isSecure":true,"isUseProxy":false}

Here is what I need:
{"id":"YXe1yCcNlc","settingName":"AAAA","host":"AAAA","port":0,"username":"AAAA","password":"AAAA","senderName":"AAAA","senderEmail":"AAAA","senderMessageIdDomain":"AAAA","senderReplyTo":"AAAA","senderListUnsubscribe":"AAAA","isSecure":true,"isUseProxy":false,"proxyhost":"AAAA","proxyport":0,"proxyusername":"AAAA","proxypassword":"AAAA"}

Thank you very much my friends.

I have readed many faq and guids ... but I didnt find any solution ...

Comment: Move the `Proxy` class out of the `SmtpData` And give it a Property of type `Proxy` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your Class declaration isn't neat, and that is confusing you.

```
public class SmtpData
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string settingName { get; set; }
        public string host { get; set; }
        public int port { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string senderName { get; set; }
        public string senderEmail { get; set; }
        public string senderMessageIdDomain { get; set; }
        public string senderReplyTo { get; set; }
        public string senderListUnsubscribe { get; set; }
        public bool isSecure { get; set; }
        public bool isUseProxy { get; set; }

        public Proxy proxy { get; set; }
        
    }

    public class Proxy
    {
        public string proxyhost { get; set; }
        public int proxyport { get; set; }
        public string proxyusername { get; set; }
        public string proxypassword { get; set; }

    }
```

Define your classes as such, and try to deserialize again. Should give you, your expected outcome.

Comment: Thanks ... just try it ... but I have an error on Winform, in the proxy text box
System.NullReferenceException:

Comment: Did you set the 'proxy' value?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to change the result string with Json value, insert the serialized `SmtpData.Proxy` into serialized `SmtpData`. Or using reflection and `JObject`.

Because your class `Proxy` is not a part of the `SmtpData` class, if you add a `Proxy` property:

```
{"id":"YXe1yCcNlc","settingName":"AAAA","host":"AAAA","port":0,"username":"AAAA","password":"AAAA","senderName":"AAAA","senderEmail":"AAAA","senderMessageIdDomain":"AAAA","senderReplyTo":"AAAA","senderListUnsubscribe":"AAAA","isSecure":true,"isUseProxy":false, "**proxy**":{ "proxyhost":"AAAA","proxyport":0,"proxyusername":"AAAA","proxypassword":"AAAA"}}
```